# changing views in android on a touch event

Tags: android

I am trying to create my first game for android. I currently have a title page with some graphics and a 'start' button.

What I am trying to do is load the game once the start button is pressed.

Here is my activity code:

```
 public class TitlePage extends Activity {

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
                            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
    setContentView(new TitlePageView(this));
    }
```

The class `TitlePageView` deals with loading & placing the images on the canvas, checks if the button is pressed and draws some balls floating around the screen.

Once the button is pressed, I don't really need anything at all from the `TitlePageView` class. Is there a way of deleting the current view, and calling `setContentView()` with a different view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have implemented your own SurfaceView class to show the game content, i.e.

```
public class GameView extends SurfaceView implements ...... { ....}
```

then in your `TitlePage` Activity, initilize an instance of the GameView, like:

```
GameView mGameView=new GameView(this);
```

When you want to show your game, simply call `setContentView(mGameView)`;
Of course, you may call something like `mGameView.start()` to start the game.

Comment: Yep that is what I have done. I am not sure how to call `setContentView()` from my `TitlePageView` class though.

Comment: No, you should call 'setContentView()' in he 'TitlePage' class. When you call`setContentView(new TitlePageView(this));` the screen show the title page of you game. When you call `setContentView(mGameView)`, it shows your game. It seems that you are confused with a Activity and a View.

Comment: That's what I thought, but the action listener for the start button is in the `TitlePageView` class. How can I inform the `TitlePage` that the button has been pressed?

Comment: Ok, I think in game development,you might not use the normal views like Button, TextEdit, etc, but draw them by yourself. So it would be more convenient for your control. In your case, I think you can set up a onTouchEvent() Listener, so the TitlePage Class can know when you touch the screen and click the Button.

Comment: Or you can do this. Use a singleton pattern or transmit the `TitilePage` instance as a parameter in the construction method of the `TitlePageVIew`. So you can get access to the TitilePage instance and call setContentView();

Comment: Again, for an App other than a game, you can use built-in View like Button, TextView, and in this case, when you want to show something different on the screen, you can simply call `startActivity()` to start another Activity. However, in a game development, you had better draw everything by yourself, so you make your UI consistent and/or draw some beautiful graphics by your will. I think it would look ugly and weird when the usesr see the normal views and the game content at the same time.

Comment: Thank you for the help Huang. I managed to get the desired functionality by keeping track of the TitlePage instance like you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of switching contentView's  you should use  a surfaceView which will be invalidating inside a running thread ,for better performance .
a very useful link for android 2d Game is [here](http://www.droidnova.com/playing-with-graphics-in-android-part-i,147.html)

Comment: my `TitlePageView` class does extend SurfaceView. I have a thread that runs to update some bouncing balls on my title page. Do I add a conditional `invalidate()` call in there?

Comment: No, you don't have to, because it extends `SurfaceView`, the view can update itself directly in the running thread. When you use a normal View, you should update the canvas in UI thread by calling `invalidate()`; or in the non-UI thread by calling `postInvalidate()`;